# Julias set visualization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, math

I have to deal with Julias set visualization.
I found nothing more or less similar to my code, so I still cant resolve this problem.
I found tutorial, but its in russint, if anyone can read it here is the link:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/206516/#comment_7114136

Here is my code:

```
 public class JuliaSet
{

    ModelCanvas canvas;

    public JuliaSet(ModelCanvas canvas, Complex c, int w, int h, int maxIter,
    double xMin = Double.NaN, double yMin = Double.NaN, double xMax = Double.NaN, double yMax = Double.NaN)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;

        double r = CalculateR(c);
        if (Double.IsNaN(xMin) || Double.IsNaN(xMax) || Double.IsNaN(yMin) || Double.IsNaN(yMax))
        {
            xMin = -r;
            yMin = -r;
            xMax = r;
            yMax = r;
        }
        //Logger.Instance.Log("R = " + r);
        double xStep = Math.Abs(xMax - xMin) / w;
        double yStep = Math.Abs(yMax - yMin) / h;
        //XBitmap bmp = new XBitmap(w, h);

        IDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, int>> xyIdx = new Dictionary<int, IDictionary<int, int>>();
        int maxIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            xyIdx.Add(i, new Dictionary<int, int>());
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                double x = xMin + i * xStep;
                double y = yMin + j * yStep;
                Complex z = new Complex(x, y);
                IList<Complex> zIter = SqPolyIteration(z, c, maxIter, r); 
                int idx = zIter.Count - 1;
                if (maxIdx < idx)
                {
                    maxIdx = idx; // maxIdx = 1 
                }
                xyIdx[i].Add(j, idx);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                int idx = xyIdx[i][j]; 
                double x = xMin + i * xStep;
                double y = yMin + j * yStep;
                Complex z = new Complex(x, y);
                //bmp.SetPixel(w - i - 1, j, ComplexHeatMap(idx, 0, maxIdx, z, r));
                this.canvas.SetPixel(w - i - 1, j, ComplexHeatMap(idx, 0, maxIdx, z, r));

            }
        }
        // return bmp;
    }

     public byte[] ComplexHeatMap(decimal value, decimal min, decimal max, Complex z, double r)
    {
        byte[] color = new byte[4];
        decimal val = (value - min) / (max - min);
        color[3] = Convert.ToByte(255 * (Complex.abs(z) / r > 1 ? 1 : Complex.abs(z) / r));
        color[2] = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
        color[1] = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
        color[0] = 255;

        return color;
    }
    private static IList<Complex> SqPolyIteration(Complex z0, Complex c, int n, double r = 0)
    {
        IList<Complex> res = new List<Complex>();
        res.Add(z0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (r > 0)
            {
                if (Complex.abs(res.Last()) > r)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            res.Add((res.Last() * res.Last()) + c);
        }
        return res;
    }
    private double CalculateR(Complex c)
    {
        return (1+Math.Sqrt(1+4*Complex.abs(c))) / 2;
    }
}
```

everything is copied from the tutorial, but everything I get is a circle which is slowly changing its color closer to center. So all the pixels are getting same color value, and all the pixels are set. May be anyone can find here a mistake, I know that this is to specific question, but I cant resolve it on my own.

As well here is the code for drawing(setting pixels/ colors)

```
  public class ModelCanvas
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    private byte[, ,] pixels;
    private byte[] currentColor = { 0, 0, 0, 255 };


    public ModelCanvas(int width, int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;

        pixels = new byte[width, height, 4];
        Array.Clear(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    }

    public void SetCurrentColor(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte alpha)
    {
        currentColor[0] = b;
        currentColor[1] = g;
        currentColor[2] = r;
        currentColor[3] = alpha;
    }


    public void SetPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        SetPixel(x, y, currentColor);
    }

    public void SetPixel(int x, int y, byte[] colorData)
    {
      for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
          pixels[x, y, i] = colorData[i];
      }
    }

    public WriteableBitmap GetWriteableBitmap()
    {
        int imageHeight = pixels.GetLength(1);
        int imageWidth = pixels.GetLength(0);

        WriteableBitmap wbitmap = new WriteableBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

        byte[] pixels1d = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 4];
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < imageHeight; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < imageWidth; col++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    pixels1d[index++] = pixels[col, row, i];
            }
        }

        Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        int stride = 4 * imageWidth;
        wbitmap.WritePixels(rect, pixels1d, stride, 0);

        return wbitmap;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of c? There are a lot of different shapes the Julia set can take which depend on the value of c used. With c=0 the Julia set is the unit circle. Look at the examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set which gives the expected shape of the Julia set for different c.

Comment: c is set from 2 input fields one for real part, second for imaginary part. Have tried a lot of combinations.

Comment: For reference: you could find some glsl implementations on [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've translated the code to Java and it works correctly.

All I did was convert various methods to their Java equivalents.

```
package toys;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Julia extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage image;

    static class Complex {
        double x,y;

        public Complex(double x, double y) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public static double abs(Complex last) {
            return Math.hypot(last.x, last.y);
        }

        public Complex mul(Complex last) {
            double z = x * last.x  - y * last.y;
            double w = x * last.y + y * last.x;
            return new Complex(z,w);
        }

        public Complex add(Complex last) {
            double z = x + last.x;
            double w = y + last.y;
            return new Complex(z,w);
        }

    }
    public void JuliaSet(BufferedImage canvas, Complex c, int w, int h, int maxIter) {
        double xMin = Double.NaN;
        double yMin = Double.NaN;
        double xMax = Double.NaN;
        double yMax = Double.NaN;

        double r = CalculateR(c);
        if (Double.isNaN(xMin) || Double.isNaN(xMax) || Double.isNaN(yMin) || Double.isNaN(yMax))
        {
            xMin = -r;
            yMin = -r;
            xMax = r;
            yMax = r;
        }
        //Logger.Instance.Log("R = " + r);
        double xStep = Math.abs(xMax - xMin) / w;
        double yStep = Math.abs(yMax - yMin) / h;
        //XBitmap bmp = new XBitmap(w, h);


        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> xyIdx = new HashMap<>();
        int maxIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            xyIdx.put(i, new HashMap<>());
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                double x = xMin + i * xStep;
                double y = yMin + j * yStep;
                Complex z = new Complex(x, y);
                Deque<Complex> zIter = SqPolyIteration(z, c, maxIter, r); 
                int idx = zIter.size() - 1;
                if (maxIdx < idx)
                {
                    maxIdx = idx; // maxIdx = 1 
                }
                xyIdx.get(i).put(j, idx);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                int idx = xyIdx.get(i).get(j);
                double x = xMin + i * xStep;
                double y = yMin + j * yStep;
                Complex z = new Complex(x, y);
                //bmp.SetPixel(w - i - 1, j, ComplexHeatMap(idx, 0, maxIdx, z, r));
                canvas.setRGB(w - i - 1, j, ComplexHeatMap(idx, 0, maxIdx, z, r));


            }
        }
        // return bmp;
    }

    public int ComplexHeatMap(double value, double min, double max, Complex z, double r)
    {
        double val = (value - min) / (max - min);
        byte red = (byte) (255 * (Complex.abs(z) / r > 1 ? 1 : Complex.abs(z) / r));
        byte g = (byte) (255 * (1 - val));
        byte b = (byte) (255 * val);
        byte a = (byte) 255;

        int color = (red<<16) + (g <<8) + (b) + (a << 24); 
        return color;
    }

    private static Deque<Complex> SqPolyIteration(Complex z0, Complex c, int n, double r)
    {
        Deque<Complex> res = new ArrayDeque<>();
        res.add(z0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (r > 0)
            {
                if (Complex.abs(res.getLast()) > r)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            res.add( res.getLast().mul(res.getLast()).add(c) );
        }
        return res;
    }
    private double CalculateR(Complex c)
    {
        return (1+Math.sqrt(1+4*Complex.abs(c))) / 2;
    }

    int h,w;
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            h  = 400;
            w =  400;
            image = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            this.JuliaSet(image, new Complex(0.285,0.), w, h, 20);
//            System.arraycopy(source, 0, dest, 0, w*h);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


    }
}
```

And here is the output, which looks correct.

[image]

So I'm not sure what it wrong with your C# version. It might be in the implementation of the Complex type.

Comment: I had the most stupid mistake ever, it was in my Complex class, so I didnt get correct complex numbers.